# SQL Server XPath Query to Extract ArrayOfString

Tags: c#, sql-server, xpath

How do I write an xpath query to return to be an object that'll have an array of string? Can't seem to get value or string to work.

```
<Info>
  <EmailAddresses>
    <string>email1</string>
    <string>email2</string>
    <string>email3</string>
  </EmailAddresses>
</Info>

SELECT Table.[Object].value('(//Info/EmailAddresses)[1]','nvarchar(max)') As 'EmailAddresses' from Table where ...
```

leads to Cannot implicitly atomize or apply 'fn:data()' to complex content elements, found type 'ArrayOfString' within inferred type 'element(

```
SELECT Table.[Object].query('(/Info/EmailAddresses)[1]') As 'EmailAddresses' from Table where ...
```

will return the whole

```
  <EmailAddresses>
    <string>email1</string>
    <string>email2</string>
    <string>email3</string>
  </EmailAddresses>
```

which makes it odd to parse in code since it'll have to be transferred to object instead of list of string in C#

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using (please update tags accordingly)....

Answer (score 0):

this example query returns list of emails from your xml

```
declare @x xml
set @x = 
'<Info>
  <EmailAddresses>
    <string>email1</string>
    <string>email2</string>
    <string>email3</string>
  </EmailAddresses>
</Info>'

SELECT r.nref.value('.','nvarchar(max)') As 'EmailAddresses' 
from @x.nodes('/Info/EmailAddresses/*') r(nref)
```

and then you can parse strings in this resultset in any way you want in C# - put them in array of strings or something ...